# Setup Postfix and Dovecot with mysql but can't receive mail for users defined in database

Tags: mysql, postfix, database, email-server, dovecot

I setup Postfix and Dovecot with mysql but can't receive mail for users defined in database.

Actually I can login to webmail and even send mail.

```
Remote host said: 550 5.1.1 <mail@example.org>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table [RCPT_TO]
```

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: you might want to provide `postconf -n`  and some information about your user table / contents of your postfix virtual_mailbox_maps file etc. . With the current information I don't think anyone will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
local_recipient_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
```

in /etc/postfix/main.cf

This fixed my issue.